# MongoDB $jsonSchema Validation Error in Compass - "Unknown $jsonSchema keyword"

Tags: mongodb, jsonschema, mongodb-compass

I'm using Compass's validation tab to manually enter the $jsonSchema validation below.
Unfortunately it keeps showing the error "Unknown $jsonSchema keyword: geometry"

Not sure why this error is showing, since geometry is being used as a key.

Any advice on how I can correct this please?

```
{
  $jsonSchema: {
    bsonType: "object",
    required: ["properties.Name", "properties.Country", "geometry.type", "geometry.coordinates"],
    properties:{
      Country: {
        bsonType: "string",
        description: "Must be supplied"
      },
      Name: {
        bsonType: "string",
        description: "Must be supplied"
      },
      description: {
        bsonType: "string",
        description: "Optional description"
      }
    },
    geometry: {
      type: {
        bsonType: "string",
        enum: ["Point"],
        description: "Must be Point"
      },
      coordinates: {
        bsonType: ["double"],
        description: "Longitude, Latitude"
      }
    },
    datePosted: {
      bsonType: "date",
      description: "Auto-added field"
    },
    image: {
      bsonType: "string",
      description: "URL of image location"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Check if your MongoDB vesion is >= `3.6`

Comment: Yes, server version is 4.2.2

Answer (score 1):

The JSON Schema you have supplied doesn't look quite right. The error about the unknown "geometry" keyword is because that attribute should describe one of your properties.  The structure of the JSON Schema file is rigid and follows a tight (but admittedly confusing) spec.

I see a few things wrong with the schema you supplied:

1. The array of `required` properties should list the keys within the
   `properties` object.  So in your case, it should be something like
   `required: ["Name", "Country", "geometry"]`
2. The `geometry`, `datePosted`, and `image` objects need to be placed inside the `properties` object.
3. The description of the `geometry` object must itself be another JSON Schema (it's a recursive pattern).
4. What is the geometry type? You have defined it as a string and as an enum with only one possible option ("Point"). Enum's only make sense if you provide multiple options, and their values would supersede the data type specified.

The code below is tested on MongoDB Compass:

```
{
  $jsonSchema: {
    bsonType: 'object',
    required: [
      'properties.Name',
      'properties.Country',
      'geometry.type',
      'geometry.coordinates'
    ],
    properties: {
      Country: {
        bsonType: 'string',
        description: 'Must be supplied'
      },
      Name: {
        bsonType: 'string',
        description: 'Must be supplied'
      },
      description: {
        bsonType: 'string',
        description: 'Optional description'
      },
      geometry: {
        type: 'object',
        properties: {
          type: {
            'enum': [
              'Point'
            ],
            description: 'Must be Point'
          },
          coordinates: {
            bsonType: [
              'object'
            ],
            description: 'Contains Longitude, Latitude',
            properties: {
              longitude: {
                type: 'number',
                description: 'Decimal representation of longitude'
              },
              latitude: {
                type: 'number',
                description: 'Decimal representation of latitude'
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      datePosted: {
        bsonType: 'date',
        description: 'Auto-added field'
      },
      image: {
        bsonType: 'string',
        description: 'URL of image location'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Have a look at the example in the docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/

Answer (score 0):

geometry is innerjson object so you need to mention what type of this innerjson object
geometry:{
bsonType:'object'} then mention required fields